# Which process is causing high software interrupts?

Tags: top, cpu-usage

I am running virtual machines on a physical host using *devstack* and I see very high `si` usage on one core. Is there a way to find out which process is responsible for this high `si` usage?

[image: top screenshot]

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/326300/how-to-find-the-processes-which-are-hogging-the-machine

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)